# Strip leading zero in Perl decimal operand?

Tags: perl, shell, makefile

Here's a Makefile one-liner which returns a timestamp as a 16-bit hex integer:

```
DAY       := $(shell date +%u)
HOUR      := $(shell date +%H)
MINUTE    := $(shell date +%M)
TIMESTAMP := $(shell perl -e 'printf "%04X", ($(USER2)<<14)|($(DAY)<<11)|($(HOUR)<<6)|$(MINUTE)')
```

This works, most of the time. However, if I run it right now `date` returns an hour of `09`, and the script complains:

`Illegal octal digit '9' at -e line 1, at end of line`

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert numeric literals into strings by quoting them. This will do the right thing together with the bitshift operators.

```
"$(USER2)"<<14
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll check at 09:00 tomorrow!